# Element not interactable (Input field) when sending keys

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, input

I'm trying to login to this website using Selenium:
https://www.gamingintelligence.com/my-account

I've done this so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

username = 'my_user'
password = 'my_pass'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='./chromedriver')

url = "https://www.gamingintelligence.com/my-account"

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-login-tab"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
```

But I get this error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

The HTML is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control xh-highlight" name="username" 
id="username" autocomplete="username" value="" required="" style="background- 
image: ...">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve exactly this issue you'll need to add explicit wait:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username = 'my_user'
password = 'my_pass'

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')

url = "https://www.gamingintelligence.com/my-account"

driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-login-tab"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-login-tab"]').click()
field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="username"]')))
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(username)
```

Or, you can set implicit wait, just after `driver.get()`:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
```

First way is more reliable.